# Question about dictionary assignment in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I wonder why this code produces prints out True:

```
rec = {"Name" : "Python", "Age":"20", "Addr" : "NJ", "Country" : "USA"}
id1 = id(rec)
del rec
rec = {"Name" : "Python", "Age":"20", "Addr" : "NJ", "Country" : "USA"}
id2 = id(rec)
print(id1 == id2)
```

Well as far I know, if we were to change something in id1 then rec would also change. so why does not that code deletes id1, as rec is deleted?

Comment: The Python interpretor does save memory and it allocates the same memory cells for existing constant dict. You can see the same with identical strings for example.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "if we were to change something in id1 then rec would also change". `id1` is an integer, `rec` is a dict.

Comment: It prints out `False` for me.  Return value of `id` is based upon memory location of object, and it's none of your business whether Python chooses to reuse same memory location or put in fresh location.

Comment: Because rec is a name but not a variable. In Python you create variables implicitly. When you type a = ..., then you match an implicit variable to a name a.

Comment: This is implementation specific and not at all guaranteed to be reproducible.  In CPython the id of an object is just its address in memory, so since you created two dicts of the same size in succession it happened to reuse the same memory allocation.  This has nothing really to do with assignment.  Objects in Python have an id whether or not they're assigned to a variable :)

Comment: ``id`` is not the identity function in Python. ``id(rec)`` returns the memory address of ``rec`` in CPython.  This does not depend on the value or lifetime of ``rec``. Similarly, releasing ``rec`` (via ``del``) allows something else to be stored at that address. Whether this happens or not is an implementation detail of the memory management.

Comment: @sergzach `rec` is still, for all intents and purposes, a variable. It's just not semantically the same as a variable in a language like C.

Comment: Even if you *did* have two names referring to the same `dict` (e.g., `rec2 = rec`), `del rec` does not delete the `dict` object. It simply reduces the reference count of the object by 1, since the reference `rec` is released. When an object's reference count reaches 0, it is eligible for (and often immediately undergoes) garbage collection

Comment: @chepner `rec` is a named reference to be clear. If we call named references variables, then I think you are right.

Comment: @sergzach We do. There's nothing else in Python that we would use the term "variable" for, so we use it for the obvious candidate.

Comment: @chepner With classical variables we can't assign them to data structures of another types. With named references we can do that.

Comment: @sergzach You keep referring to the semantics of other languages. In Python, a variable is a name that refers to an object. Period. Objects have types, names don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a very technical answer, specific to *CPython*, the reference Python implementation (which most people, I assume here included, mean by default when they say "Python"):  Many common object types in Python are allocated from something called a "free list" which is an array, or in some cases I think a linked list, of objects of the same type for which memory has already been allocated.  This means, for example, that many short-lived dictionaries can be created and destroyed quickly by reusing the same memory allocation for a single dict over and over rather than repeatedly malloc/free-ing them.

For example for `dict` objects the freelist can be seen here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/61289d436661025a3111065482275d49a4850b8d/Objects/dictobject.c#L252

(There is also a separate one for dictionary keys, which I'll ignore for now.)

When a new `dict` is created, the [`new_dict`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/61289d436661025a3111065482275d49a4850b8d/Objects/dictobject.c#L597) function first checks if there is an empty slot in the `free_list`, and if so reuses it (slightly pseudo-code reinterpretation):

```
PyDictObject *mp;
if (numfree) {
    mp = free_list[--numfree];
    _Py_NewReference((PyObject *)mp);
}
else {
    // Allocate a new PyDictObject
    // Note, we do NOT put this on the freelist yet since it's still in use;
    // we'll do that later
    mp = PyObject_GC_New(PyDictObject, &PyDict_Type);
}
```

Later, in [`dict_dealloc`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/61289d436661025a3111065482275d49a4850b8d/Objects/dictobject.c#L1977), which is called when there are *zero* references to your object remaining, if there is room on the `free_list` we keep our object there rather than free its memory:

```
if (numfree < PyDict_MAXFREELIST && Py_TYPE(mp) == &PyDict_Type)
    free_list[numfree++] = mp;
else
    Py_TYPE(mp)->tp_free((PyObject *)mp);
```

To be clear, note that the `PyDictObject`s that are stored in the `free_list` does *not* necessarily mean that any of their keys or values are kept in memory too.  This is just for the `PyDictObject` itself which contains pointers to arrays for the keys/values as well as a bit of additional internal book-keeping.

If it happened that your initial `del rec` freed up a slot in the `free_list`, then immediately creating a new dict (regardless of its contents) would use that same slot, and hence have the same `id()` since in CPython `id()` just returns the memory address of an object.  Of couse, this could also happen by chance fairly easily even without the free list.

Answer (score -3):

id1 is an independent variable. It has been assigned a value from the rec. Now if rec is deleted, id1 has a separate value stored in it which is not inside that dictionary rec. That is why it is not deleted